# Performance of Hibernate or JDBC for write operations

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I have a doubt if an application has more number of writes than reads, which performs better Hibernate or JDBC? .

My understanding is that for reads hibernate is fast because it uses cache mechanism. But for writes both are same as hibernate internally fires a JDBC query.

But there I am missing a significant difference between the two for writes
Kindly help me point out.

Comment: Hibernate generates SQL statements that are sent using JDBC to the database. There is no difference in performance. That is just the short answer. There are many other aspects in SQL performance optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is a layer on top of JDBC, so Hibernate will be at best as fast and in most case slower than a pure well-crafted JDBC application.

That being said hibernate performance are pretty good and more than enough for lots of project, the only real issue could be the start-up time with a lot of entity.

Comment: Unless Hibernate does many optimizations behind the scenes that the custom JDBC solution doesn't do because they're not so easy to do, like batch inserts, dirty checking avoiding useless updates, lazy inserts and updates avoiding useless queries in case an exception is thrown later, etc. So the answer is: it depends on how well the code of both solutions is written.

Comment: I totally agree with you that's what i tried to express (may be not well enough), plus hibernate give easy access to complex feature. Yes JDBC is natively faster but the ratio performance/time spend is totally different.